# Configure netplan programmatically

Tags: c, linux, networking, netplan

Is there a way to configure netplan programmatically using a coding language (e.g. c or c++)?

What I mean is calling api functions instead of writing `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` and calling `sudo netplan apply`.

Comment: You could always write your own API that manipulates `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` and calls `sudo netplan apply`.

Answer (score 2):

netplan can be accessed via d-bus (ubuntu manpage: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/netplan-dbus.8.html).

The idea is to connect your program to the d-bus and invoke the commands there.

Note that this requires root privileges and if you haven't programmed with a c++ d-bus lib this might take some time to understand everything (at least it took me some time ;) ). I would recommend d-feet if you want to check out the structure of the netplan d-bus interface.